# Yeoman : no generator installed error

Tags: yeoman, angularfire, yeoman-generator, yeoman-generator-angular

I'm trying to setup angularfire generator.
I did `npm install -g generator angularfire`
The generator was installed successfuly.
And when I run `yo angularfire` in my newly created directory,it asks few options like `firebase instance` and which modules to include , but after that it shows the following error

```
You don't seem to have a generator with the name angularfire:common:C:\Users\SATWIK\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-angularfire\app\index.js installed.
```

Also I've checked that the file `index.js` does exist at this path.

As suggested in some of the answers on stackoverflow I've also tries `npm install -G generator-angularfire` and `npm install generator-angularfire` but none of them worked.
I also did `yo doctor` but it shows Everything is fine . Is there any fix to this problem?

Comment: I think that's a bug we introduced in the last version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a regression we had in our last release. It's now fixed https://github.com/yeoman/environment/releases/tag/v1.5.2

`npm -g update yo` to fix that issue.

Comment: I ran `npm -g update yo` but nothing happened (as there's probably an issue when updating on windows) . So I installed npm again and the yeoman put the same problem still persists! By the way, `yo --version` gives 1.6.0

Comment: Uninstall and reinstall then.